# In python the result of a /= 2.0 and a = a / 2.0 are not the same

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [67]: import numpy as np
In [68]: a = np.arange(10)
In [69]: b = a.copy()
In [70]: a /= 2.0
In [71]: a
Out[71]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
In [72]: b = b / 2.0
In [73]: 
In [73]: b
Out[73]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```

I don't know why it the results are different when try to deal with numpy array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`a = np.arange(10)` has an integer dtype.

```
>>> np.arange(10).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Modifying an array inplace -- for example, with `a /= 2.0` -- does not change
the dtype. So the result contains ints.

In contrast, `a/2.0` ["upcasts" the resultant array](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5) to float since the divisor is
a float.

---

If you start with an array of floating-point dtype, then both operations yield the same result:

```
In [12]: a = np.arange(10, dtype='float')

In [13]: b = a.copy()

In [14]: a /= 2.0

In [15]: a
Out[15]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])

In [16]: b = b / 2.0

In [17]: b
Out[17]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```